# QT Creator C++ Grouping Function Symbols in a Class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a bunch of functions, 20+ or so in a single C++ Class. Same can be seen here:

[image]

I am dire need or organizing these into different sections, what is the best way to do the same besides using namespace?

Comment: You can't even use namespace if these are members of a class. It's unclear what exactly you want. Do you want the drop-down list in Qt Creator organized? You can't, it's sorted alphabetically.

Comment: What do you mean by "different sections"? Please be more specific and descriptive.

Comment: The only way I can think of is, is putting them in different cpp's...

Comment: @Jaa-c you are right, I want them organized.

Comment: @Amfasis The class is actually registered as a QML component that has an established communication over modbus, I dont see how I can put them in different cpp's.

Comment: @PraneethPeiris I want to organize the drop down list in groups instead of being organized alphabetically.

Comment: @AakashThakkar No matter if they are registered for QML or not, you can have multiple cpp files, you should tell the compiler to compile them all (add them in the .pro/CMakeList) and the linker will link them to be one class. This way you have some freedom in sectioning the functions, however you will not see all the function in that same dropdown